# Does one ever use an iframe to make ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I can't find any resources for this, but I just have this wonder.
Does one ever use an iframe to handle ajax to hide, say long poll requests, and other information from the web console?

Is this a practice, and does it work the way I imagine it ( hiding requests and header information as well as response)

Comment: As far as I know in Chrome Developer Tools, you can see all requests even if done in an iframe

Comment: I see, are there any benefits to using an iframe with ajax requests, or is ajax just great as it is?

Comment: No benefits that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use an iframe to "hide" AJAX requests, but there are a few circumstances where you might use an iframe for communication to a server:

1. Since file uploads must happen by submitting a form, some websites [use iframes to enable asynchronous file uploading](http://ramui.com/articles/ajax-file-upload-using-iframe.html). I think this is mostly necessary on older browsers.
2. You typically cannot perform AJAX requests directly to a different domain than the one the page was loaded from unless it has [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) set up, and the browser supports CORS. Some websites provide a way to load a portion of their site in an iframe. This portion of their site is free to communicate via AJAX with their site to allow users, for example, to share a link on a social network site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide your ajax requests simply by placing them in an iframe, (at least Chrome's Developer tools will still show them). And no, this isn't a common practice anyway, doing a google search you won't find anyone doing that. And finally, there are no apparent benefits to doing it that way.